# Show the system of differential equations has the solution of the form $ \phi(x)=e^{kx}\alpha$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the following linear system
>   $$y_1 '=ay_1+by_2$$$$y_2 '=cy_1+dy_2$$
>   where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. Then show that this system always has a solution $\phi(x)=e^{kx}\alpha,$ where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\ne(0,0)$ is a constant vector and $k$ is a constant.

My approach was to suppose $\phi(x)$ to be a solution and define the function vector $\psi(x)=e^{-kx} \phi(x)$. And show that $\psi'(x)=(0,0)=\mathbf 0$ by using the given system and the fact that $\phi(x)$ is the solution. However, I did get a trouble in showing that $\psi'(x)=(0,0)=\mathbf 0$.

Could anyone give me a hand on this part? OR does anyone have a simpler way to show this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You aren't asked to show that EVERY solution is of the form $e^{kx}\alpha$; you're just asked to show that you can choose $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\neq(0,0)$ and $k$ such that $\phi(x)=e^{kx}\alpha$ **is** a solution.

Here, you're trying to take $y_1=\alpha_1e^{kx}$ and $y_2=\alpha_2e^{kx}$, and you want
$$
\begin{align*}
k\alpha_1e^{kx}&=a\alpha_1e^{kx}+b\alpha_2e^{kx}=(a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2)e^{kx},\\
k\alpha_2e^{kx}&=c\alpha_1e^{kx}+d\alpha_2e^{kx}=(c\alpha_1+d\alpha_2)e^{kx}.
\end{align*}
$$
So, you want to show that you can choose $\alpha$ and $k$ such that
$$
k\alpha_1=a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2\qquad\text{and}\qquad k\alpha_2=c\alpha_1+d\alpha_2.
$$
Can you figure out how to do that?  Again, you don't need to find EVERY solution -- just **a** solution.

Comment: Well, what is left will be linear algebra. To make sure the system for $\alpha$ has the non-trivial solution, we need the rank of the coefficient matrix to be less than 2, or equivalently, we need the determinant to be 0. This will help us to find the value of k. Then, we could figure out the values of $\alpha$. Is this what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

A different way to approach the problem: we can write this system as $\vec y' = A\vec y $, where $\vec y = (y_1\quad y_2)^T$ and
$$ 
A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}
$$
Now, $A$ must have some eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector.  Let $k$ be this eigenvalue and let $\alpha$ be this eigenvector.  Show that $\phi(x) = e^{kx}\alpha$ is a solution to this system of differential equations.